# Regexp, выделяющий фразы не входящие в скобки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Важна совместимость с JS

```
Hello ([me]) no[this]
```

Выделить: this

Дальше чем

```
/\[.*?\]/g
```

Не ушёл, к сожалению.

Comment: Увы, но такой постановкой вопроса, вы дальше и не уедете!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно Вас понял, то дана строка `Hello ([me]) no[this]`. В ней нужно найти/выделить содержимое между `[...]`, но только втом случае, если вокруг `[...]` нет скобок: `([...])`?

Вариант пока не самый идеальный, но работает:

```
/// 1. Ищем все что находится между '[' и ']' и не является символом ']':
/// 2. Сохраняем это в группу.

            \[([^\]]+)\]

/// 3. Делаем это только в том случае, если после ']' нет ')'

            (?!\))

/\[([^\]]+)\](?!\))/g
```

Искомая строка (`this`) будет находиться во второй группе match-a. Пример: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/T7m87/)**